# Can I store a definition of a sql column in a variable so that I can later use it again in a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that is stored in a view:

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(session_id, 0, CHARINDEX('-', session_id)) AS part_id,
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB ON SUBSTRING(session_id, 0, CHARINDEX('-', session_id)) = tableB.part_id
```

Is there a way to store the `SUBSTRING(session_id, 0, CHARINDEX('-', session_id))` column definition in variable so that my query would instead look something like this?

```sql
@PartIdColumnDefinition = SUBSTRING(session_id, 0, CHARINDEX('-', session_id))

SELECT 
@PartIdColumnDefinition AS part_id
....
JOIN tableB ON @PartIdColumnDefinition = tableB.part_id
```

Thanks! (I am using MSSQL btw)

Comment: You could define the value in `VALUES` table construct in the `FROM`. Though, honestly, if you need that expression as a `JOIN` criteria, I would ask why it isn't stored in the table in the first place. It can be a (`PERSISTED`) calculated column, if needed.

Comment: `SUBSTRING(session_id, 0, CHARINDEX('-', session_id))` is an expression, not a column definition. What you ask is already possible with subqueries or CTEs - you're trying to join on the *result* of that expression, not the expression itself. `FROM (SELECT
    SUBSTRING(session_id, 0, CHARINDEX('-', session_id)) AS part_id,
FROM tableA) as A INNER JOIN ... ON A.Part_ID=tableB.part_id`. That said, this will have *very* bad performance, because there's no way to use an index to speed up looking in the middle of a field.

Comment: Variables, however, cannot be used as replacements for expressions. A (scalar) variable, stores a scalar value, and when a comparison is performed against that variable, it would be equivalent (in behaviour) to comparing to a literal of the same value as the value within the variable.

Comment: short answer - no. long answer, what are you trying to simplify? do you want to reuse some expression in many views for different tables? that is not possible

Comment: oh. if you just wanna avoid typing it out in same view, you can use CROSS APPLY (select somecomplexexpression as xx) x then you can use x.xx in the rest of the view

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple view and use it your further queries instead of table:

```
CREATE viewA AS 
(
  SELECT
    SUBSTRING(session_id, 0, CHARINDEX('-', session_id)) AS part_id
  , *
  FROM tableA
)
```

--

```
SELECT part_id,...
FROM viewA a
JOIN tableB b ON a.part_id = b.part_id
```

Comment: There's no need for a view

Comment: Or just use a CTE.

Comment: Or a subquery. Performance will be awful

Comment: Of course they can use CTE or subquery, but my understanding was they want to somehow save the definition and not type it every time, which simple view can provide. Creating a computed column would be even better.